Short story where a man summons demon who mocks him for not believing in God
I read this short story a while ago and can't for the life of me find it again. I think it might have been around the time that the SFX Pulp books were released and the aliens found humans were intelligent meat.
Anyway what I remember was a man summoned a demon and the demon laughs at him when the man claims there is no god. The demon goes off about how this man was so arrogant to believe that throughout all of human history, people have had faith and this man assumes he is better than them and more intelligent.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about when you read this?

One of my old SFBC books by Ben Bova had this plot.

Hi Spencer would you have any idea of a title of this, I've checked some Ben Bova shorts but cant see it.
